# How to find latest filename based on the version info in the filename

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

I have a senario in which, for a particular feed, files with different version can be published.

Eg

1. abc.xml
2. abc-v01.xml
3. abc-v02.xml
   and so on...

But when I need to fetch the feed file I need to get the latest file. In this example, I am expecting output to be string abc-v02.xml

In my code I get the a List of string having all file path of all the feed files shared.

At present I am trying to iterate the list in foreach loop, extract out the version part in the file name.

I think, there should be better way to find this string, among the list of strings, using linq or regex.

Please help out in finding the best possible way to find the latest version file name.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track:

Parse the version using regex and convert to int, then compare.

Alternatively, if you have access to feed, supply another property per file: publishedDate or something similar.

Comment: Files being published by external 3rd party. They have specified the way to detect the version is by looking at file name part (v01..)

Comment: Then I guess parsing the filename is the way to go.